# vite: use "keep-names" esbuild flag for production build

Tags: vite, minify, esbuild, terser

one of our third party libraries requires us to preserve specific function names. in webpack we did that with `terser.keep_fnames`. esbuild has https://esbuild.github.io/api/#keep-names so we'd like to use that but we cannot find how to enable this option for a vite production build.

according to the docs esbuild is used for minification. how do we enable this flag (or a comparable option)? note that we'd like to not use terser, as its much slower than esbuild.

there is an undocumented `config.esbuild` prop. that seems to be used in the current master code:
https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/f72fdc7c995db502ca89f0057cfc1fcd6660212f/packages/vite/src/node/plugins/esbuild.ts#L352

but when i tried adding `config.esbuild.keepNames` to the config object (as object fields of course) it didnt do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for our **ForgeViewer** friends, here's some more context for the solution:

when using a custom query function to query the property database, you need to define a function that is called `userFunction`. as this function gets serialized and sent to the web worker, you need to make sure the function name is not mangled, when using a bundler.

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/propdb-queries/

in **webpack** this is done via a `terser` plugin. where you need to set `keep_fnames: true` for `terserOptions`

**vite** uses esbuild, so we need to supply the config in our `defineConfig`

```js
  esbuild: {
    minifyIdentifiers: false,
    keepNames: true,
  },
```

additionally, make sure you **dont inline the function definition** for `userFunction` in the call like we did before:

```js
//doesnt work
  await viewer.model
    .getPropertyDb()
    .executeUserFunction(function userFunction() { ... }, {
      dbIds,
      propertyNames,
      includeRevitCategory,
    });

// works
  function userFunction() {
    // ...
  }
  await viewer.model
    .getPropertyDb()
    .executeUserFunction(userFunction, {
      dbIds,
      propertyNames,
      includeRevitCategory,
    });
```

not mangling any function names in the whole codebase leads to an increase in bundle size. we only needed to preserve the function name `userFunction` so I instead opted to use `terser` instead, in `vite.config` (dont forget `npm add -D terser`)

```js
  build: {
    minify: 'terser',
    terserOptions: {
      mangle: {
        reserved: ['userFunction'],
      },
    },
```

for us this was a 22,2% decrease in client bundle size, which is a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
esbuild: {
    minifyIdentifiers: false
},
```

seems to have done it for me